# How can I display the multiple selected value from a user in the following function?

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Function StartTableCell( _
  Optional ByVal align As String = "", _
  Optional ByVal valign As String = "", _
  Optional ByVal colspan As String = "", _
  Optional ByVal rowspan As String = "", _
  Optional ByVal width As String = "", _
  Optional ByVal height As String = "") As String

    Dim _StrBuil As New StringBuilder()

End Function
```

How can I display the values from the arguments where the caller has passed in a value? For example if `align` is `""` it should not be displayed.

Comment: if user donot give input value to some attribute that can not be display..for eg. in the output align = " " should not be display...display those vlaues which is specify by the user in start table cell function.....plz help me

Comment: In what format is the result expected? Comma separated, with a prefix?

Comment: in the source code of result i want <td align="left" valign="top" etc...>those value should be displayed that is given by the user that should be display in the souce code of result not in the main result....plz help me dave.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to check each argument and build up the `StringBuilder` one by one.

For example:

```
Dim _StrBuil As New StringBuilder()
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(align)
    _StrBuil.Append(("align: """ + align + """")
End If
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(valign)
    _StrBuil.Append(("valign: """ + valign + """")
End If 
'etc.  
Return "<td " + _StrBuil.ToString + ">"
```

Comment: in the source code of result i want <td align="left" valign="top" etc...>those value should be displayed that is given by the user that should be display in the souce code of result not in the main result....plz help me dave.....

Comment: thank you very much dave ..........your solution is working well.....thank you so much....

Comment: @ruchitpatel I am no VB Expert, in C# I may have done it another way, but it works, so that's enough for me ;)